# Debug webpage redirects in browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

I am debugging a web application which redirects several times on page load.  Page A redirects to page B, which redirects to page C. I don't know what methodology is used (e.g. JavaScript, HTTP redirects, etc.).

What I'm looking for is a debugger to break before a page gets redirected, so that I can inspect exactly what method is being used to redirect, and what data is being sent to next page in the redirect chain.

Is there a simple way to do that? I'm debugging on Windows, so Chrome, Firefox and IE are all available.

**UPDATE**: It seems that Fiddler is the best option available. I marked the answer from @cgatian as a solution, since his was the Fiddler idea.

Comment: Any of those browsers have networking tools to diagnose. I prefer Fiddler. http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: fiddler is an option, but won't let me inspect state of javascript variables, scripts or HTML code as it is on the moment of redirect

Comment: The only way to do that, is to inspect the JavaScript and put a break point where the code makes the redirect.

Comment: Or I have another idea. Let me test it out and ill get back to you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright so it sounds that you want to actually look at variables inside the browser before the redirect occurs.  One way I can think of (without modifying the source directly) is to use Google Chrome Snippets.

You could create you're own snippet that binds to the onbeforeunload event.

[Step By Step Instructions on Creating a Snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets)

**Snippet code:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
var debug;
return;
}
```

All I am doing in the above code is attaching an event before the browser would be redirected.

[image: Visual of chrome]

If you then place a break point inside your snippet you will be able to break and inspect the variables on the page. (Don't forget to right click your snippet and select Run) before debugging.

Comment: very good idea, however a) doesn't work for some reason when i click on <A>, which probably means redirects done via form.submit() will not be caught, and b) works on current document, but since page A is gone before I open dev console and run snippet, no use. But thanks for the effort, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 21):

In Chrome there is `Event Listener Breakpoints -> Sript -> Script First Statement`:

[image: Breakpoint on Srcipt First Statement]

Pressing F8 will stop on first statement of any script in page, e.g :

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.location.href='http://www.example.com'</script>
```

Also, there is `Event Listener Breakpoints -> Load -> beforeUnload` but not works in my case.

Comment: Thank you, you saved the day :)

Answer (score 4):

In chrome, in the debug window, at the very bottom, are a series of buttons. Click the button that is a dark black circle. It will preserve the log upon navigation. I think that is what you want.