# How can I tell what initiated a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, safari

I have a webapp that makes use of websocket (`io`) to communicate with the backend. (It uses Underscore and JQuery, but nothing fancier like React.) In Safari, every few minutes the page refreshes.

How can I tell what made that happen? In the Developer Tools Network tab I see an xhr and other requests, but how do I see what line of  Javascript initiated that?

[image]

Stopping on the `beforeunload` event in the debugger does not show anything in the call stack.[image]

Comment: Did you find the `initiator` column in the tab?

Comment: `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { debugger; }, false)`

Comment: Not a real dupe, but the answers (other than the accepted one) might help nevertheless: [How to use Chrome's network debugger with redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987453/how-to-use-chromes-network-debugger-with-redirects)

Comment: Better dupe candidate: [Debug webpage redirects in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477825/debug-webpage-redirects-in-browser)

Comment: @ikvjs Where would I see this tab? Note the screenshot -- I don't see it there

Comment: @andreas  -- thank you for the snippet.  But when the debugger stops, it is of course in the unload listener, which does not have the original cause of the reload in the call stack. How do I find the cause of the reload?

Comment: @JoshuaFox, you quote my name wrongly...nvm, I post my answer.

Comment: _"it is of course in the unload listener, which does not have the original cause of the reload in the call stack."_ - In Chrome I see the source of the redirect in the callstack: https://imgur.com/rOd0WvX

Comment: @andreas Stopping on the `beforeunload` event in the debugger does not show anything (beyond that debugger callback itself) in the call stack in Safari. (See body of question.) 
 The reload behavior does not happen for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a column `initiator` in the Network tab. You can see what initiates the network.

note: Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In Safari, I had to enable that column --  now I haveit.

Comment: The Initiator column showed me that socket.io was doing the reloading. The specific filename + line number was  apparently incorrect (looking both at the minimized file and the original) but for now I will assume -- without much evidence -- that this issue is specific to Safari and that Safari has some limitation the prevents websockets from working in their normal way, so that there is a fallback to a full page load after some timeout.